# Игнорируется if

Tags: android

Вот скрипт в котором if просто игнорируется системой

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    rt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.r);
    mont = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mon);
    nastt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nast);
    subt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    nick1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nick);
    piar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.piar);
    zbnach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zbnach);
    stream = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stream);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nick = intent.getStringExtra("");
    nick1.setText(nick);

   piar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           sub=sub+15;
           mon=mon-50;
           rt.setText("Рейтинг"+r);
           subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
           nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
           mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
       }
   });
    stream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sub=sub+10;
            mon=mon+(sub/2);
            rt.setText("Рейтинг"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
        }
    });
    zbnach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            r=r-10;
            nast=nast+5;
            rt.setText("Рейтинг"+r);
            subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
            nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
            mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
        }
    });
    if (nast<=0){
        Intent i1;
        i1 = new Intent(this, LoseActivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Он не игнорируется. У вас либо условие не проходит, либо активити запускаемая не обозначена в манифесте. Либо включен `InstantRun` в настройках студии и этот код не попал на девайс

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все прописанно, а ошибка была даже на устройстве после компиляции. причем даже если в тело if поместить другую команду эффект нулевой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы условие поместили в метод onCreate(), который вызывается один раз при загрузке Активити. Когда ему выполнить условие, если переменная будет меняться за пределами onCreate ()? По моему в этом проблема.

Создайте метод (после onCreate())

```
private void myIfMethod(){
if (nast<=0){
    Intent i1;
    i1 = new Intent(this, LoseActivity.class);
    startActivity(i1);
   }
}
```

и вызывайте его в каждом слушателе, если такова задача. Например

```
zbnach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        r=r-10;
        nast=nast+5;
        rt.setText("Рейтинг"+r);
        subt.setText("Подписчики"+sub);
        nastt.setText("Настроение"+nast);
        mont.setText("Деньги"+mon);
        myIfMethod();//<--------- 
    }
});
```